# How to use Carbon PHP to get "hours ago" for a millisecond epoch timestamp?

Tags: php

I have tried this, where `$time = 1409065068000.`

```
$ago = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($time)->diffInHours();
```

That time stamp is from somewhere in August 26th. But my code returns me:

```
391015508
```

It shouldn't be like this. The hours ago should rather be 48 or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` implies you're trying to get a different between two values, but the only value you've supplied is your timestamp. So Carbon's probably going against your time v.s. the epoch:

```
1409065068000 / 1000 = 1409065068 seconds
1409065068 / 60 / 60 = 391406963 hours
```

If you'd read the docs: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-difference you'd see that the various `diff` functions take in another carbon object that you want to diff against.

Comment: How about I do this, substr($time, 0, - 3), is that risky? I do get 47 which is the correct answer. I think Carbon needs to have functionality for milliseconds.

Comment: that depends on how accurate you want to be. if the millisecond value awas 999, I'd consider that time+1 second, instead of truncating it down to the next lower full second.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but since I want hourly functionality, that shouldn't pose a serious threat to the accuracy. :) Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

`Carbon::createFromTimestamp` takes epoch timestamp in seconds as input. If you want to input epoch timestamp in milliseconds then you can use  `Carbon::createFromTimestampMs`

```
$ago = Carbon::createFromTimeStampMs($time)->diffInHours();
```

This will return the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may solve your problem-

```
$time = $dt->timestamp(1409065068000)->timezone('Europe/London');

echo Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(Carbon::now()->subYear($time));
```

Try for this code, hope it will work. 
However, it is highly recommended to take a look following tutorials-

- https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon
- http://tisuchi.com/php-date-time-customization-carbon/